# How to extend a component screen in Moqui?

Tags: erp, moqui

I'm trying to modify the structure of a screen. Specifically, I want to add button to System/dashboard.xml. The problem is the screen doesn't iteratively build its buttons from its subscreens as webroot/apps/AppList.xml does. They are hardcoded.

I considered two solutions:

1. Just override dashboard.xml from my component
2. Inject javascript into dashboard.xml to dynamically create the button

Solution 1 would work but it's obviously not desired as it could create clashes with other components also wanting to modify dashboard.xml and using the same method.

I haven't been able to get around implementing solution 2, as, if I understand correctly, the mounted dashboard.xml subscreen with the javascript would not execute in dashboard.xml as it's not in the url path. A solution would be to reverse the mount order, and mount dashboard.xml under the javascript screen but that would create a problem similar to solution 1.

So, is there a standard or recommended way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of extending it there are three ways I am thinking you can do it.

The first one is including the screen in you extended screen using the tag

```
<include-screen location"component://path/to/component"/>
```

You can combine it with `<include-screen ...share-scope="true" />` so that both pages operate in the same context.

The second one is using a parametrization so when you include the screen depending on a flag the third button is added or not:

```
<actions>
   <set field="parameterName" value="1"/> <!-- or 0 -->
</actions>
<widgets>
...
 <include-screen location"component://path/to/component"/>
...
</widgets>
```

And in dashboard.xml

```
<parameter name="parameterName" />
<!-- then use conditional-field or if tag to show conditionally -->
```

The third one is trying to replicate the menu structure at webroot/apps/AppList.xml, just as tabs, and menus do.